# Identify differences in row with duplicate values

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

I don't know if I'm phrasing the question correctly, but I'm trying to figure out how to identify differences in a row based on duplicate values in particular cells (image below). For example, if I wanted to highlight rows where the price of a specific fruit changed, i.e., lemons and pears, how can I do this and what is the proper way to phrase my question?

[image]

Comment: Use conditional formatting with averageif.

Comment: like (for range A:B) the conditional formatting formula: `=COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)<>COUNTIFS($A:$A,$A1,$B:$B,$B1)` ???

Comment: A friend of mine suggested using Concatenate to create a new column and then conditionally format the unique (or duplicate) values to identify changes. It works, but I'd love to know if there's a "better" way.

Comment: You don't like my formula? You also could enter it in C1 and copy down (will show TRUE if a change has happened and FALSE if not...

Answer (score 0):

*the proper way to phrase my question?* is a Q for [SO meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

For formatting, please clear any Conditional Formatting from ColumnsA:B, select from A3 to wherever in ColumnB required and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=($A2=$A3)*($B2<>$B3)
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select formatting of choice <kbd>OK</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd>.